# Elasticsearch: Duplicate properties in a single record

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have to find every document in Elasticsearch that has duplicate properties.  My mapping looks something like this:

```
        "type": {
        "properties": {
            "thisProperty": {
                "properties" : {
                    "id":{
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "other_id":{
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
```

The documents I have to find have a pattern like this:

```
    "thisProperty": [
    {
        "other_id": "123",
        "id": "456"
    },
    {
        "other_id": "123",
        "id": "456"
    },
    {
        "other_id": "4545",
        "id": "789"
    }]
```

So, I need to find any document by type that has repeat property fields. Also I cannot search by term because I do not what the value of either Id field is. So far the API hasn't soon a clear way to do this via query and the programmatic approach is possible but cumbersome. Is it possible to get this result set in a elasticsearch query? If so, how?

(The version of Elasticsearch is 5.3)

Comment: If you are talking about just any field, say id repeating itself, then you could do this by using the multi-termvectors api and using a filter with min_term_freq set to 2. Probably you would have to use it once for each field

Comment: @sramalingam24 Interesting.  Let me read up on this and try to form a query.  I'll post it when it's complete.

Comment: Cool. Just to point out the obvious this will not return the entire doc content but only the ids and the terms in the field.